# Where clause with IF condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I'm having a little trouble getting to work as I want, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  hf.file_path AS image,
  hop.order_product_name AS product,
  hop.order_product_price AS unit_flat_price,
  .... <SHORTENED DOWN QUERY> ....
  hc.currency_symbol AS currency,
  ho.order_payment_method AS payment_method,
  ho.order_created AS created
FROM
  shop_order AS ho
LEFT JOIN
  shop_order_product AS hop ON ho.order_id = hop.order_id
LEFT JOIN
  shop_product AS hp ON hop.product_id = hp.product_id
LEFT JOIN
  shop_file AS hf ON(
    IF(
      hp.product_parent_id > 0,
      hp.product_parent_id,
      hp.product_id
    )
  ) = hf.file_ref_id
LEFT JOIN
  shop_currency AS hc ON ho.order_currency_id = hc.currency_id
WHERE
  ho.order_id = X AND(
    hf.file_ordering = 0 OR hf.file_ordering = NULL
  )
```

Now my issue is that sometimes the shop_file table won't have a match in the `shop_file`table and then I need my query to "ignore" that join, but if there IS a match, then I need it to apply the `AND` part in the `WHERE` clause I've tried

```
WHERE
  ho.order_id = X (
    IF(
      hf.file_path = NULL, 
      '',
      AND(
        hf.file_ordering = 0 OR hf.file_ordering = NULL
      )
    )
  )
```

I tried with different values at the `hf.file_path =` line but nothing helped, I still got a syntax error `#1064 - You have an error in your .... syntax to use near '( IF(`

I also tried

```
WHERE
  ho.order_id = X AND(
    hf.file_id = NULL OR(
      hf.file_ordering = 0 OR hf.file_ordering = NULL
    )
  )
```

But that simply returns a empty result set (where if I remove the entire `AND( ... )` part I get my desired result.

Now I know I can do something along the lines of

```
WHERE
  ho.order_id = X AND(
    IF EXIST(SELECT file_path FROM ... )
```

But that would require me to add the other `JOINS` in that query to get the right result (in case there is a image) and I want to try and avoid having to add the JOIN's in the `WHERE ... AND( IF_EXIST (SELECT` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add CASE into your where statement.

Try this, by adding this to your WHERE clause:

```
AND CASE
WHEN hf.file_path IS NOT NULL
THEN hf.file_ordering = 0 OR hf.file_ordering IS NULL END;
```

Comment: Afraid that also returns a empty result set.

Comment: you are afraid or you where check this ?. If the file is not null then the additional condiftion will add to the where statement. This is what you want so dont understand what you are afraid of ?. This will return empty set from hf table when conditions will not match - its simple. I've edited last comment, there should be IS NULL not = NULL

Comment: I ran the query with the code in your answer and it returned a empty result set, "afraid" is a way of speech, it's uh, a polite way of saying "it doesn't work." - Like this http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/when-can-you-use-im-afraid-that

Comment: Ah, do I feel stupid now, your answer worked mostly, I just had to add a `ELSE 1` (or true) and it worked flawlessly in every instance I tested.

Comment: thanks for exmplanation of afraid word :). Good to hear that it works :)